# How to read all lines in map (mapreduce)

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

`Map(offset,text)` read only one line per time. My file includes many lines and each line represents a data in 3D: `x1,x2,x3`.
I want to choose n of them from the block, which have most high density.
（And then choose n data from the result of all `map()` again through `reduce()`）
So I should calculate all data's average distance(Euclidean distance) between each other in `Map()`,so I think I should read all lines in,and then put them in an array then use  `for{for{}}`to calculate the average distance.

I check the code for class `LineRecordReader` and know how to read several lines everytime:(use `for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){}`)

```
public boolean nextKeyValue() throws IOException {
    if (key == null) {
      key = new LongWritable();
    }
    key.set(pos);
    if (value == null) {
       value = new Text();
    }
    int newSize = 0;
    // We always read one extra line, which lies outside the upper
    // split limit i.e. (end - 1)
    boolean flag=true;

    int len =(int)fileSplit.getLength();
    String aString = fileSplit.toString();
    for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){
        if(i==2){
            flag=false;
        }
        while (getFilePosition() <= end || in.needAdditionalRecordAfterSplit()) {
            if (pos == 0) {
                newSize = skipUtfByteOrderMark();
            } else {
                newSize = in.readLine(value, maxLineLength, maxBytesToConsume(pos),flag);
                pos += newSize;
            }

            if ((newSize == 0) || (newSize < maxLineLength)) {
                break;
            }
            // line too long. try again
            LOG.info("Skipped line of size " + newSize + " at pos " + 
               (pos - newSize));
        }
    }
    if (newSize == 0) {
      key = null;
      value = null;
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
}
```

but I don't know how to read all lines in.
How can I get the number of rows of the block? T T
I hope somebody can help me.Thank you very much!!

Comment: kindly clarify a bit more. You have already implemented a custom `lineReader` to read 5 lines, so what is the problem?

Comment: @gyan thanks for your comment. How can I get the number of rows of the block? T T

Comment: Why do you need to know number of rows in the block. The logic of a `RecordReader` has the responsibility to return a `record` and it automatically jumps to the next block in order to complete the last partial record, if any.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think MapReduce is a good choice for this.

But you can do the following in your **Mapper** class:

1. Initialize an empty list in **setup()** method
2. Put everything you get into the list in **map()** method
3. Do the calculation and flush out the results in **clean()** method

Comment: Thank you very much for the  answer! Is that mean calculating all data in input.txt file in cache??

Comment: It means all data in `input.txt` was cached in your **Mapper**. But if the input.txt is big, maybe each **Mapper** could see only part of the file.

Comment: If there is only 1 mapper, Why do you want to use MapReduce in the first place?